# Como ocultar elementos dinamicos en react?

Tags: reactjs, web, hide

Intento hacer una galeria dinamica no logro que refresque la galeria como tal registro los cambios en la interfaz de seleccion y modifico el state donde tengo las imganes y la propiedad de view y en el primer run si oculta o muestra lo que por defecto ponga en visible = true sin embargo cuando cambio la categoria o galeria seleccionada si cambia mi stado catImagenes pero no se refresca el let galery :( solo ocupo que se renderize ese elemennto cada que cambie mi categoria seleccionada

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { Row, Col, CardGroup, Card } from 'react-bootstrap'
import './styles.css'

const BancoDeImagenes = () => {
// Contexto de obra para saber que obra esta seleccionada
const selectedObra =( isNaN( parseInt(window.localStorage.getItem("selectedObra")))) ? 1 :  parseInt(window.localStorage.getItem("selectedObra"));

const [ oobras, setOobras ] = useState()
const [ residente, setResidente ] = useState()
const [ categoriasImagen, setCategoriasImagen ] = useState()
const [ catImagenes, setCatImagenes ] = useState()    

useEffect(async () => {
    getCategoriasImagen()
    fillGelery()
    await getOObras()
}, [])
useEffect( async () => {
    getCategoriasImagen()
    fillGelery()
    await getResponsables( )
   
},[oobras,selectedObra])

const getOObras = async () =>{
    const res = await axios.get( process.env.REACT_APP_BACK_ATISA_ROUTE + 'api/oobra')
    if (res.status ===200){
        const obra = res.data.filter( obra => obra.idobra === selectedObra )
        await setOobras( obra )
    }
}

const getResponsables = async () =>{
    const res = await axios.get( process.env.REACT_APP_BACK_ATISA_ROUTE + 'api/responsable')
    if (oobras && res.status ===200){
        const getResidente = await res.data.filter( resi => resi.idResponsable === oobras[0].idResidente)
        setResidente(getResidente)
    }
}

const getCategoriasImagen = async () =>{
    const res = await axios.get( process.env.REACT_APP_BACK_ATISA_ROUTE + 'api/categoriasimagen')
    if (res.status ===200){
        const getCI = await res.data.filter( ci => ci.idobra === selectedObra)
        setCategoriasImagen(getCI)
    } 
}


 const fillGelery = () => {
    let galery = []
    if(categoriasImagen){
        categoriasImagen.forEach( cat => {
            galery.push({
            categoria : cat.nombre,
            visible : false,
            imagenes : [ 
                { key : 1, img : cat.imagen1, text : cat.texto1},
                { key : 2, img : cat.imagen2, text : cat.texto2},
                { key : 3, img : cat.imagen3, text : cat.texto3},
                { key : 4, img : cat.imagen4, text : cat.texto4},
                { key : 5, img : cat.imagen5, text : cat.texto5},
                { key : 6, img : cat.imagen6, text : cat.texto6}
            ]
        })
    });
    if (galery.length > 0){
        galery[0].visible = true
    }
    setCatImagenes(galery)        }
    
} 

const onChangeCategoriasHelper = (e) => {
    catImagenes.map( (currentValue) => { currentValue.visible = ( currentValue.categoria === e.target.value ) ? true : false })
}

let galery = <CardGroup>
    {catImagenes && catImagenes.map( categoria => {

        return(
            <div>
                {
                    <Row xs={1} md={3} className="g-4"> 
                        {categoria.imagenes.map(img => (
                            <Col>
                                <Card>
                                    <Card.Img variant="top" src={img.img} />
                                    <Card.Body>
                                        <Card.Text>
                                            {img.text}
                                        </Card.Text>
                                    </Card.Body>
                                </Card>
                            </Col>
                        ))} 
                    </Row>
                }    
            </div>
        )
        })}
</CardGroup>

return (
    <div>
        
        <Row className = "row row-header-general" >
            <Col className = "col col-header-general" >
                <section>
                    Residente : <b>{residente && residente[0].nombre}</b>
                </section>
                <section>
                    Reporte NO.:
                </section>
            </Col>
            <Col className = {"col col-header-general"} >
                <section>
                    Semanas Transcurridas:
                </section>
            </Col>
            <Col>
                <section>
                    Periodo:
                </section>
            </Col>
        </Row>
    
        <Row className = "header" >
            BITÁCORA FOTOGRÁFICA
        </Row>   
        <Row>
            <Col sm = {10}>
                {galery}
            </Col>
            <Col className = "menu-galery" sm = {2} onChange = { onChangeCategoriasHelper }>
                <b>BITÁCORA FOTOGRÁFICA</b>
                
                {catImagenes && catImagenes.map( (categoria, index ) => {

                    return(
                        <div> 
                            <input type="radio" id={categoria.categoria} name="categorias" value={categoria.categoria}/>
                            {categoria.categoria} 
                        </div>
                    )
                } )}
                
            </Col>
        </Row> 
    </div>
)}
export default BancoDeImagenes
```

Ese es el codigo que tengo igual este es el [gist](https://gist.github.com/odmox/1485b6be13eaae812561b8a2308db89b)

La imgaen de el componente ya montado :)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

No detectaba el cambio en el state de "catImagenes" ya que este lo hacia modificandolo desde un map y no usando el setCatImagenes que declare en el useState

```
const [ catImagenes, setCatImagenes ] = useState()
```

por lo que podia usar el set del useState sin embargo declare un state que guardaba el valor seleccionado por los radio button

```
const [ catSelected, setCatSelected ] = useState()
```

y cuando modifico mi estado catImagenes en el map solo hago set de la variable catSelected con el setCatSelected que activa el render de nuestra galeria y carga las imagenes correctas

```
const onChangeCategoriasHelper = (e) => {
    
    catImagenes.map( (currentValue) => { 
        currentValue.visible = 
            ( currentValue.categoria === e.target.value ) 
                ? true 
                : false 
    })
    setCatSelected(e.target.value)
}
```

y es todo se encuentra funcionando perfectamente gracias espero que ayude a alguien que se le presente el mismo problema